# definir usuario shell para chamar script no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell-script

Preciso chamar um script shell a partir do rails, com um usuário shell específico.

Exemplo:

```
update_response = `#{deploy_dir}/./update.sh`
```

Por padrão meu sistema esta usando usuário root.

Gostaria de saber, dado esse exemplo, se tem como especificar o usuário e se possui um meio para generalizar as chamadas de script para um mesmo usuário.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar sudo -u nome_usuario

Answer (score 0):

Solução encontrada foi utilizando o próprio shell para realizar a chamada do script com outro usuário.

```
update_response = `su -c '#{deploy_dir}/./update.sh' - #{user}`
```

Podemos a partir dessa solução criar uma função genérica para chamadas de scripts passando path do script e um usuário por parâmetro.